# How to fix installation error -504?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, motorola-moto-g2

I'm using Moto G second generation. My device is unable to install Facebook app after completion of download from play store. I checked few solutions, even removed my google account, but didn't work. I have enough space on my device and a fair connection speed. This problem is occurring only with Facebook application.
Although, I tried to download Facebook from other sources but still there's problem in installation.

Comment: Possibly not. This error is occurring with Facebook app only.

Comment: Is it "-504" or "504"? If it's the latter, then it's a duplicate. However, I didn't find other occurrences of "error -504" on Google.