# Error -504 on appliation installation

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, installation, system-error

Yes. I've read all other questions regarding this problem.
Like this one:
[Error 504 when downloading apps from Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35062/error-504-when-downloading-apps-from-play-store/46095#46095)
It's the same problem as this one but with more background information and an other app:
[How to fix installation error -504?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101993/how-to-fix-installation-error-504)

The details:
My device is an Ulefone Be Touch 2 running Android 5.0.

My connection is perfect. To be sure I tried different networks, among them are 3G, 4G and wifi on ADSL, VDSL, cable and fiber. I've also used Tor and 3 different VPN providers in 3 countries on 2 continents. Let's say I ruled the network out.

- A single app does not install: OpenKeychain.
- Currently I have 126 apps installed.
- It does not install via desktop browser > play store > install
  button.
- I have enough free space (40GB). The app is 7MB.
- Re-adding Google account and clearing caches did not work.
- Even a complete device wipe and re-install didn't work.
- Downloaded the apk and tried manual installation, same error.

I also own a Nexus 7 (2013 wifi) and the app installs fine on that device.

Comment: 1) put the device in airplane mode for ~60 seconds, then reboot, turn off airplane mode, download again. OR TRY 2) turn off data/wifi for ~90 seconds, then turn back on, download again. ///you can also sideload the app. ///If the choices (1 or 2) help let me know and I'll post as an answer. ///Did you force stop apps before clearing data??

Comment: The more I read about it and reread what you wrote, I'm thinking you have an issue with your ROM.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in Lollipop, I found this on another app forum:

> I’m getting the Error Code -504 (INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED) when installing App from Google Play
>
> Try to erase the “/data/data/appnamespace” directory on your device and try again. This is a “bug” Android 5.0 Lollipop developer preview which was fixed in the final release version.

That (plus a reboot, remove + reinstall of the app and remove + replace of my google account) fixed this issue for me.

It definitely isn't a connectivity issue, and it's nothing to do with a 504 HTTP error.

Comment: I'm not sure that the namespace directory is for this app. I've tried to remove com.android.keychain and that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Thijs I think they can change directories so it may be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1) Clear data/cache for for the following apps:

- Google Play Store
- Google Play Services
- Download Manager
- Google Services Framework
- Google app
- Chrome

2) Restart the device

3) Change time and date, then back to the actual time and date.

Source: https://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-50875-5-1.html